# Is there a way to use the smaller Alpine-based OpenJDK image with the Ktor Gradle plugin?

Tags: ktor

In the build.gradle.kts of my ktor Gradle app, I use the following to set the JRE version to be used for the Docker base image. The plugin selects the base image "eclipse-temurin:17-jre". That works well. As that image is rather large, I'd like to use the smaller "eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine" image instead. After reading the documentation I don't see how to do it. How can I do it? :)

```
ktor {
    docker {
        jreVersion.set(io.ktor.plugin.features.JreVersion.JRE_17)
    }
}
```

If there is no such feature, perhaps it can be added like below?

```
ktor {
    docker {
        jreVersion.set(io.ktor.plugin.features.JreVersion.JRE_17)
        versionSuffix.set("alpine")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try using the `jib.from.image` system property to specify the name of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring it like this

```
jib {
    from {
        image = <IMAGE_YOU_WANT_TO_USE>
    }
}
```

And build it with gradle

```
./gradlew jibDockerBuild
```

And if you want to use it in CI and pass argument from there, configure it like this

```
jib {
    val image = project.properties["image"].toString()
    
    from {
        image = <IMAGE_YOU_WANT_TO_USE>
    }
}
```

And build like this

```
./gradlew jibDockerBuild -Pimage=name
```